# Call the Java script to set value after values loaded in dot net drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dropdown

Need help to insert an item value into drop down list(asp.net).
Using java script values should be inserted into drop down index 0 value.

ddlState having lists but index 0 should be set from previous page.

Coming from page 1 where state showing as KER when i open page 2 state name KER should be taken using Javascript and set as initial drop down value .

```
Protected void page_load()
{ 
    this.BindCountrydropdown();
} 

public void Bind_ddlState()  
{  
    conn.Open();  

    SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand("select State,StateID from countryState where CountryId='" + ddlcountry.SelectedValue +"'", conn);  

    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();  
    ddlstate.DataSource = dr;  
    ddlstate.Items.Clear();   
    ddlstate.Items.Add("--Please Select state--");  
    ddlstate.DataTextField = "State";  
    ddlstate.DataValueField = "StateID";  
    ddlstate.DataBind();  
    conn.Close();  
}
```

"Please Select state" should show below Java script value (“StateName”) from previous page. Drop down list loaded once second page opened from 1st page. Java script should set value after page load"

```
function loadState()
{
    document.getElementById(“ddlState”).value=window.opener.parent.document.getElementById(“StateName”).value;
}

  <body onload =“ loadState()”>

     <asp:DropDownList ID=“ddlState” runat =“server”> </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Your code has smart quotes in it, suggesting that you've pasted this from Word, or something similar. `“` should be `"`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you leaving out a boatload of details here.

So, we have web page 1, user selects country, and then selected state (two values).

They then are to hit a button and we jump to page 2.

On page two, we want to load up the drop down list, and set it to the same state value chosen on the previous page.

Since we loading up the ddl, and since the page load WILL run, then I see no need, nor advantage or benefits by attempting to use JavaScript for this purpose. Perhaps if we were to remain on the one page - maybe JavaScript might help, but since we are jumping and navigating to a whole new page, then JavaScript not really required, and benefits us in no way that I can determine.

So, say we have a drop down, on page 1

This:

```
<h4>Select State</h4>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
    DataValueField = "Alphacode"
    DataTextField = "State"  Width="160px" >
</asp:DropDownList>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
    Text="Jump to next web page" CssClass="btn" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

And our code to load that ddl is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadCombo();
    }

    void LoadCombo()
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSource = 
            General.MyRst("SELECT AlphaCode, State FROM tblStates ORDER BY State");
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select State", "0"));

    }
```

And now we have this:

[image]

So, we select a state from the drop down, and hit the button to jump to the 2nd page.

[image]

And now we click on the button:

[image]

So, our button click now has to pass the value to the next page

So, say this code for the button click:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["StatePick"] = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value;
        Response.Redirect("WebFormB.aspx");
    }
```

Now, we jump to our 2nd page WebFormB.aspx.

So, this page has the same drop down but we need to pass/set/get the value from the previous page.

So, we have this markup:

```
  <h4>This is web page B</h4>
  <h4>Select State</h4>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"
            DataValueField = "Alphacode"
            DataTextField = "State"  Width="160px" >
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

So our page load (ALWAYS use !IsPostBack stub in on-load), has to load up the ddl, but ALSO set the value from the previous page:

eg this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadCombo();
    }

    void LoadCombo()
    {
        DropDownList1.DataSource =
            General.MyRst("SELECT AlphaCode, State FROM tblStates ORDER BY State");
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
        DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select State", "0"));

        // select state pick from previous page.
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = Session["StatePick"].ToString();

    }
```

So, now when we select a ddl, then click button to jump to next page, we get this:

[image]

So, SINCE you note we are to jump to a whole new page, then really no JavaScript code can help, will help, and as above shows, not required anyway.

Comment: 1st page value from text box of classic asp page. 2nd page drop down is asp.net. so it is difficult/unable to use session between both pages. any idea?

Comment: Well, if it still running on the same site, then you can use a cookie, or simple pass the state selection in the URL (url query parm). So, the navgate from the asp page to the aspx page can be like say MyAspPage.aspx?StateSelect="CA".  But, session between a asp and aspx page can't be used. But, leaving out you are navigating between two vast different architectures is a HUGE detail to leave out.  I would pass the value in the URL.

Comment: Thanks @Albert D.Kallal .. I could achieve with query park. 